# Calculus at competitive level or Olympiad level

Tags: calculus

What are the topics of Calculus which can be useful for competitive level and the students are not exposed to it ?

Comment: I'm not sure that this would be on topic for the site even if asked clearly, but it would be more possible to answer this question if you stated what sort of competition you are thinking of (country, age group, level). For example, if you are competing in the MIT Integration Bee, than integration will certainly help :).

Answer (score 2):

On [this page](https://www.vwo.be/vwo/wedstrijdvragen-per-jaargang-en-ronde/), you find all questions, asked during math olympiads as asked in Vlaanderen (Belgium), already from the start in 1985. The questions are written in Dutch, but there are plenty of translation websites available on the internet.
Another well-known competition is the Hungarian [Kömal](https://www.komal.hu/verseny/korabbi.e.shtml).

Have fun :-)